# Using GeoFire to store user latitude and longitude into my database - It's not updating consistently

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am creating an application that stores and updates each users latitude and longitude at regular intervals, using their UID. Currently, when the user registers for the first time, their lat/long is successfully captured and uploaded to my Firebase database using Geofire, into a table called "Geo". However, I have also attempted to implement similar code on the application main activity, so that the user lat/long is constantly updating.

My current main activity code is not flagging any errors, however the users lat/long are not updating after the initial registration. Does anyone know why this is the case?

The main activity (Cutting away as much irrelevant code as possible):

```
public class FindChatters extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

GoogleApiClient mGoogleAPIClient;
Location mLastLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public FindChatters() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_chatters, container, false);
    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    ...
    return mMainView;
}

//RETRIEVE DATA IN REALTIME
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    startListening();

}

public void startListening() {

...

//
//BUILD API CLIENT TO GET LOCATION UPDATES
protected synchronized void buildGoogleAPIClient() {

    mGoogleAPIClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API)
.build();

    mGoogleAPIClient.connect();

}

//UPDATE USERS LOCATION OVER A SPECIFIED PERIOD
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && A ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleAPIClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    buildGoogleAPIClient();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

//SAVE USERS UPDATED LOCATION TO THE DATABASE
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Geo");

    //ADD THE UPDATED USER LAT/LNG TO THE DATABASE
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    geoFire.setLocation(userID, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

}
}
```

As usual, any help is very much appreciated.

Android Studio v3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` is deprecated, try to use `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), mLocationCallback, null);` (callback from `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback`).

Second you whant to update location just when the app running? If you need to make updates all the time look to FirebaseJobDispatcher it will give you option to start update and save it every n-minutes (minimum every 20 minutes),

Also from the docs:
This interval is inexact. You may not receive updates at all (if no location sources are available), or you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive them faster than requested (if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval). The fastest rate that that you will receive updates can be controlled with setFastestInterval(long). By default this fastest rate is 6x the interval frequency.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest

And the last thing, Geofire setLocation has callback, you can make log there like:

```
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
geoFire.setLocation(userID, new GeoLocation(lat, lng), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " );
            }
        });
```

PS: good practices will be check in LocationCallback if your locationResult != null, it will be null if location service not running on device.

Comment: Thanks i have taken into account all of your recommendations. No luck yet but I will keep trying!

Comment: what is the problem now? you don`t get location updates? or it not saved to geofire?

Comment: I needed to add an if (currentUser != null) {} statement to my onLocationChanged method to stop the app from crashing. All working good now.